# Группировка данных в excel

Tags: excel

Как в таблице грамотно расположить данные. Есть данные о предмете, таких предметов N. Есть отдельный лист на котором забиты формулы. Параметрами формулы выступают параметры предмета. Необходимо применить формулу ко всем предметам.

Если более конкретно, необходимо посчитать некоторый параметр Wht для каждого колеса. В формуле для Wht используются параметры колес(bw Ft U D). Вручную подставлять значения как-то не технологично, учитывая большое количество колес(более 10)

Как это можно (и можно ли) реализовать(повысить автоматизацию)?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может быть распихать пары на разные листы и лист вывести как параметр в ячейки, или что-то такое?

Comment: Excel поймет, колесо из какой таблицы надо обсчитывать? Какое из двух, расположенных парами? Почему колеса парами? Нельзя разместить одно под другим, все в одной таблице? Покажите "живой" пример (где работают формулы), проиллюстрируйте в нем задачу

Comment: Создать таблицу, в которой 5 столбцов: *пара/колесо/параметр/обозначение/величина*. Правило хранения данных: одна запись - одна строка. Там, где формулы, создать выпадающие списки (*пара, колесо, параметр*). Из такой таблицы легко извлекать нужные данные (например, `СУММПРОИЗВ``)

Comment: @vikttur Спасибо, так и сделаю